# Download D3JS chart as png/pdf/jpeg

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have been seeking the answer to this issue,i have a D3Js chart in the form of svg.The svg has attributes of circle,text,line,images(in .png form).I am able to download the D3Js chart as a .png file ,but i am unable to get the images from the chart!.i have looked into html2canvas but it doesn't support the svg format.

html

```
 <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary " 
    style="margin-left: 5%;width: 10%;height: 70%;margin-top: 0%;"  ng-click="">
            Save as Image
 </button>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <org-chart dataobj="vm.company" ng-if="vm.company"></org-chart>
    <canvas width="1000" height="800" style="display: none;"></canvas>
    <!-- <div id="svgdataurl" style="display: none;"></div> -->
</div>
```

JS File

```
d3.select("#save").on("click", function () {

    var html = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

    var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html);
    var img = '<img src="' + imgsrc + '">';

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");


    var image = new Image;
    image.src = imgsrc;

    image.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/svg");
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = "sample.png";
        a.href = canvasdata;
        a.click();
    };
});
```

sample D3 code to build the image

```
node.append("image")
    .attr("class", "circleClass")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
        return d.photo;
    })
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        if (d.group === "Focus") {
            return -40;
        } else {
            return -25;
        }
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        if (d.group === 'Focus') {
            return -40;
        } else {
            return -25;
        }
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        if (d.group === "Focus") {
            return 80;
        } else {
            return 50;
        }
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        if (d.group === "Focus") {
            return 80;
        } else {
            return 50;
        }
    });
```

I have kind of hit the ceiling here ,i would really appreciate some help,code sample would be great
Thank You

Comment: You'd have to convert the images to data URLs first I imagine.

Comment: @RobertLongson at which part if u may direct me !,i amm very new to this whole svg /canvas thing ,i think i did convert the image to urls in the click event

Comment: d.photo needs to be a data URL (a reference to internal data) not an external reference to a png file.

Comment: @RobertLongson what's wrong with external reference ? what i mean to say ,i have the images coming from an api and there are thousands of images ,r u saying i need to save them in my project directory, check out my  "<g></g>" tag (below) generated by d3js,inside the svg element ,i am able to get the text but the problem is with the images only !!!

Comment: `<g class="node" style="fill: rgb(81, 134, 236);" transform="translate(775.2249292728861,477.93642590508136)"><circle r="9" class="circleClass" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 1px;"></circle><image class="circleClass" x="-25" y="-25" height="50" width="50"></image><text class="nodetext" dx="12" dy=".35em" style="font-size: 15px; opacity: 1; letter-spacing: 0.03em; pointer-events: none;">Tom A. Alberg</text></g>`

Comment: External refereces e.g. external images are disabled to protect your privacy when SVG is used as an image in your case via drawImage

Comment: @RobertLongson just tried using an image from my local repo,but still not printing the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132656/discussion-between-sg28-and-robert-longson).

Answer (score 0):

So ,After trying to solve this issue for few weeks ,came up with the solution
1.If there are cross domain or external source (in this case i had my images coming from AmazonS3).

1.1. Convert the whole svg to String ,i used xmlSerialize to convert the svg to string (svg is a xml data)
  1.2. Make api call to the backEnd
  1.3. receive the string ,use Apache Batik library (our backEnd was in Java SpringBoot) and convert the string to either .png/.pdf .

I have tried using canvg ,which is great but it converts the svg to a canvas and taints the canvas ,because of the external resource present in it ,(please let e know ,if there is any way change it ,i couldn't find it though).

HTML2Canvas doesn't capture the external resources present either.

I tried to work this out completely on the FrontEnd ,the best i could achieve was to print the svg on a canvas element on the page ,i could rightClick and save the image as image ,but couldn't directly download the svg to .png on the ClientSide.

**I still hope someone can give me some more suggestions & am very eager to know more about it**